# Is it possible to run multiple mDNS responders (for DNS-SD) on the same host?

Tags: networking, mdns

I'm trying to design a P2P protocol where several user applications in a residential network can discover each other. I've looked at various service discovery protocols, most notably DNS-SD with mDNS. It seems to work fine for one client discovering multiple devices, and also one device offering multiple different services that have been configured as such.

However, to my understanding there is at most one client (that sends queries and caches results) per host and at most one responder (that answers the queries) per host. So if I have multiple applications running on the same computer, they would need to share the client/responder - which appears to be a hassle, especially on Windows which doesn't offer such a service natively. Is this interpretion correct?

Or would it be possible that each application runs its own client and resolver, independent from the other applications, without conflicts?

If the answer is no, what alternatives might there be?

Comment: No, they’d all be competing for port 5353/UDP. Windows 10 has native mDNS support. For obsolete Windows versions you could have your installer install mDNSResponder.

Comment: @Spiff Thanks, that's what I thought (and I guess mDNS doesn't cope with [multiple listeners on the same port](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14388707)). Is this only a problem for responders or for clients as well?

Comment: mDNS is a peer to peer protocol, not client-server. The owner of port 5353 is expected to both ask and answer queries. I'm pretty sure it wouldn't make any sense to make an ask-only or answer-only implementation of mDNS. You *want* a single daemon on each system to be the gateway for queries and advertisements, so that it can cache responses to keep the protocol from getting too chatty.

Comment: @Spiff Oh, right. I had expected that there would be one daemon for queries and one for making advertisments, of which you would only those that are needed. A single daemon makes sense as well.

Comment: @Spiff Regarding mDNSResponder, I can only find [this undocumented Apple project](https://opensource.apple.com/source/mDNSResponder/mDNSResponder-878.1.1/mDNSWindows/) and [this old readme](https://github.com/jevinskie/mDNSResponder) seems to suggest that it would be used to create multiple monolithic applications for Windows, not a single shared service. Can you detail how to use that in an answer, please? Or did you mean "No, that's not possible, *even if* you install mDNSResponder"?